# javascript calculation outputs weird result

Tags: javascript

I am a total n00b so please be gentle, and I might not always use the correct terms...
I have a javascript which calculates a price depending on a few dropdown menus.

```
var cakePrice = getItemno()*getResolutionPrice()*getFrameratePrice() + candlesPrice() + insciptionPrice() + delValue;
```

the first 5 values come from within the script and are defined mostly by arrays. The last value (`delValue`) comes directly from the form and is read out by this:

```
var e = document.getElementById("filling2");
var delValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

And while the calculation is correct when SUBTRACTING the value, its completely wrong when ADDING `delValue`.

Can anybody give me some pointers whats wrong here?

Comment: The real explanation for the behavior you see (of the `+` operator) is found here: http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1 - note #7. Also note the behavior of the `-` operator below it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the fact that subtraction works and addition doesn't, I can only assume `delValue` is actually a string. When strings are used with the `+` operator, this operator becomes a concatenation operator and not the addition operator. `1 + "1"` is equal to `"11"`, not 2.

To fix this, use a [Unary Plus (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B)) to convert your `delValue` value to a number:

```
var cakePrice = ... insciptionPrice() + +delValue;
```

Comment: Or use `parseInt(delValue)` (assuming you are, in fact, expecting an int value).

Comment: @CharlieKilian `parseInt` is usually not a good idea (especially without a radix parameter), because it strips trailing non-digits, allowing a user to type in a number and then any characters (assuming it comes from user input), but the calculation still magically working. Even if expecting an integer, why not use `+` (or `Number()`) consistently and get consistent results?

Comment: I totally forgot about the radix. I know better! Correction would be `parseInt(delValue, 10)` assuming you're looking for decimal numbers. As for the other, I just don't think the extra `+` in front of number reads well. It's hard for a new programmer to look at that and understand why it even parses. But that's a matter of personal taste.

Answer (score 2):

When adding the value, you are adding a String to an integer,

the integer is promoted to a String and both String are concatenated.

`-` is not defined for Strings, then your String is parse to an Integer, and your Substraction is done as you expect it.